# Using IN while querying on mongoid hash field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, hash, hashmap, mongoid

I am querying a hash field on Mongoid, the name of the hash field is `keys` and the hash looks like this

```
{"location_id" => "id", "subscriber_id" => "id"}
```

Now I have an array of location ids, I want to fetch all the records having those location ids, I have tried using it with `where` like this but its not working

```
Variation.where({"keys.subscriber_id" => "id", "keys.location_id" => [location_ids]})
```

Also I tried `"keys.location_id".in => [location_ids]` but its throwing syntax error. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query methods such as `in` and `ne` are added to `Symbol`, not `String`. So you can say:

```
:'keys.location_id'.in => location_ids
```

where `location_ids` is an array. Also, the query methods are just short forms for building the longer native-style nested Hash queries. For example, if you say:

```
:field.op => value
```

for some operator `op`, then Mongoid actually sends this (JavaScript) into MongoDB:

```
field: { $op: value }
```

So if you don't want to write `:'keys.location_id'.in` then you can say:

```
'keys.location_id' => { :$in  => location_ids }
# or
'keys.location_id' => { '$in' => location_ids }
```

instead.

Also note that if `location_ids` is an array then `[location_ids]` is an array of arrays and that's not what you want in your query, you want just `location_ids` as above.